# Convert SparkR DataFrame to H2O Frame

Tags: r, h2o, sparkr

Using SparkR, I am wondering if it is possible to convert a Spark DataFrame into an H2O frame?

I have seen examples of converting R `data.frames` to h2o frames, but, sadly, this is not a viable option (data size).

I know it is possible to use `sparklyr` and `rsparkling` to create an h2o frame, but I am not using HIVE, or Hadoop, `sparklyr` or `rsparkling`.

Instead, my goal is to convert the `sdf` from this:

```
set.seed(123)
df<- data.frame(ColA=rep(c("dog", "cat", "fish", "shark"), 4), ColB=rnorm(16), ColC=rep(seq(1:8),2))
sdf<- SparkR::createDataFrame(df)
```

into this:

```
as.h2o(sdf, destination_frame = "hsdf") # fails, came from Spark (SparkR)
as.h2o(df, destination_frame = "hdf") # succeeds, but this is a regular R data.frame
```

Hopefully, someone has figured out a way to do this using what SparkR can provide. I think it would be a huge boon to R users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for converting between H2O and Spark frames natively in either the **h2o** or the **SparkR** packages.  You would have to use **rsparkling** (which depends on **sparklyr**) or do a conversion from Spark DataFrame -> R data.frame -> H2O Frame.

You mentioned Hadoop and HIVE... just to clarify, neither of those are requirements for using `rsparkling::as_h2o_frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above worked for me, the solution was:

1. Saving spark dataframe on a csv (folder csv)
2. Using apply function to open each csv file using the package Rio Import

   tmp<- lapply(list.files("data/csvfolder.csv"), function(x){rio::import(paste0("data/csvfolder.csv/", x))})
   df00<- do.call("rbind", tmp)
3. Use the "df00" as a dataframe to use as you wish,,

Hope that works for you guys! Collect and as.data.frame are too weak depending on the type of data being used.

Chers

Comment: the only issue is that this wouldn't work for very large datasets unless you're running on a massive instance type...that seems counter to the reasons I would be doing distributed computing in the first place. If I just run everything on a massive single instance, I would probably just use `doSNOW` or `parallel` libraries in R and forgo Spark altogether.